# Галереи для пунктов меню joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом для каждого пункта меню сайта можно добавить в сайдбар блок с соответствующей галереей. То есть определённому пункту соответствует определённая галерея.

Галерея представляет из себя просто набор изображений, который просматриваются через Lightbox или что-нибудь подобное.

Joomla 1.5.

Comment: Уже 3.0 вышла) 1.5 дырявая как дуршлаг

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, у вас к2.

Напрямую сделать не получится. Принцип такой:

1. Создаем нужные категории
2. Набиваем туда картинок (материалов с вложенной картинкой)
3. Создаем модуль k2Content и шаблон к нему, который будет выводить только название категории (без ссылки) + картинки из статей, что-то типа

   ```
     <? foreach($list as $item) { ?>
       <a rel="lightbox" href="<?=$item->imageXLarge?>"><img src="<?=$item->imageXSmall?>" /></a>
     <? } ?>
   ```
4. Вставляем модуль и радуемся.

С обычными материалами - ищем модуль, подобный k2Content и все то же самое.

С привязкой галереи к меню обещаю много проблем, не стоит оно того.